# how to pass data from host element to child element

Tags: polymer

Having trouble getting my data to work across elements.  Say I have an object "records" in my host element.  It is usable in that element no problem.  But when I try to spin off the view into a separate element, it no longer works.

Here's an example snippet of code.  The .template part works fine but I'm not able to replicate the functionality in the child element .my-list.  When I try, nothing happens.

```
<dom-module id="host-element">
  ...
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{records}}">
      <p>{{item.userName}} - {{item.number}}</p>
    </template>

  <my-list></my-list>    

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'host-element',
      ready: function() {
        this.records = [
          {userName: 'Bob'},
          {userName: 'Sally'}
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

If I try simply taking the current .template code and placing it into .my-list, it doesn't work.

I assume I need someway to bind the data into the child element, but I'm not able to figure this out.  Adding a:  record="{{records}}" to the tag, and then using that in the child element didn't work.

Imagine this is pretty simple, just can't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important that each element's top-level `template` is a plain template (not `is="dom-repeat"` or other specialization), otherwise, it should be straightforward:

```html
<link rel="import" href="//polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<i>(Requires Chrome)</i>

<host-element></host-element>

<dom-module id="my-list">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{records}}">
      <p>{{item.userName}} - {{item.number}}</p>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-list'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="host-element">
  <template>
    <my-list records="{{records}}"></my-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'host-element',
      ready: function() {
        this.records = [{userName: 'Bob'}, {userName: 'Sally'}];
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: awesome, didn't realize the template tag was so finicky.  Works just as I needed!